# アナログマイク使用時の抵抗値について

Tags: spresense

アナログマイクを接続して使用しています。ハードウェアドキュメントではRLとして 2.2kΩの抵抗を指定していますが、この抵抗値は使用するECMに応じて変えるものなのでしょうか。RLが2.2kΩではない（2.0kΩとか、さらに小さいものとか）ECMが手元にあるのですが、こういったECMを使うときはどうすべきでしょうか。あるいはRLが2.2kΩのECMを使うべき、なのでしょうか。

（ちなみに抵抗は表面実装ではなく金属皮膜抵抗を使っています）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エレクトレットコンデンサマイク (ECM) の原理っつかメーカーカタログ仕様上、加えるべき電源電圧ってのは決まっています。この「マイクの電源」は [spresense](/questions/tagged/spresense) のマイコン出力から取る回路となっていて、そのため [spresense](/questions/tagged/spresense) を使う限りにおいては約 1.8V から変更できないということになります。

ある仕様一覧によると
https://www.marutsu.co.jp/contents/shop/marutsu/datasheet/KUC3523.pdf
マイクの仕様として ([spresense](/questions/tagged/spresense) の仕様でなく) RL と 電源電圧が１対１で決まっている様子。
- RL=2.2KΩ なマイクは電源 2.0V
- RL=1.0KΩ なマイクは電源 4.5V

よって教科書的答えとしては「 2.0V 電源マイクを使おう」（すると必然的に RL=2.2KΩ にならざるを得ない）

アマチュアのお楽しみとしては「 RL=1.0KΩ つまり 4.5V 電源マイクに 2.0V 電源を供給して使うとどうなるか試してみよう」ってことになりそうです。

RL=2.0KΩ なマイクが手元にあるなら、それの型名から仕様書を調べて電源電圧を確認してみましょう。 2.0V 前後の電源電圧が指定されているのなら 2.0KΩ 抵抗をくっつけて動くでしょう。それ以外の電源電圧ならつないで試してどうなるか報告してね、ってことになりそうです。

RL 専用ランドが用意されているのを使うのであれば表面実装チップ抵抗を使っちゃうのが面倒ないでしょうけど、別にリードタイプを使っても問題ないっすよ。

Comment: spresense が出力しているマイク用の電源電圧が1.8Vなのだから、それで動作可能なECMを選定する、ということですね。

Comment: 今はこのECMで試していて、RLは2.2kΩなのですが、動作電圧の指定が3Vとあり、動作はするのですが音量が小さく、APIの方でゲインを最大にしてようやく聞き取れる感じです。

https://www.cui.com/product/resource/cmc-4015-25l100.pdf


件のRLが2.0kΩのECMは次のURLのもので、こちらは動作電圧が1.5Vとあるので、また違った結果になりそうです。

https://www.jp.cui.com/product/resource/cmc-9745-37l100.pdf

いろいろ試してみようと思います。

Comment: １個目：はい、そういうことです。２個目：マイクは純粋アナログ動作なので、規定電源電圧より低い電圧でドライブしてもそれなりの動作をする＝期待しているほどの出力電圧が出ないってことで予想通りですね。規定電源電圧 1.5V のブツに 1.8V を加えて絶対最大定格を超過しないことは事前に確認してからつないだほうがよさそうです（まず問題ないと思いますが）。今度は逆に音割れしちゃうかもしれないですね。